# Is there something similar to list comprehensions in Elm?

Tags: elm

If I understood it correctly Elm doesn't have something like list comprehension.

What would you use instead if you for example would like to map the numbers 1 to 100 to something else?

Comment: what's wrong with [map](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#map) ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with map but I would rather not have to enlist all 100 numbers. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: sounds like you want [range](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#range) (I'm neither a regular Elm user nor an expert so didn't know this off the top of my head, but it was easy enough to find just now by searching the documentation.) I'm not sure what this has to do with list comprehensions though - seems like your comment doesn't match with the question.

Comment: Thanks, `range` is what I need (In F# a list comprehension for generating a list of the numbers 1 to 100 would look like `let list = [1 .. 100]` )

Comment: thanks, I see. In Haskell - and indeed Python - a list comprehension is a way to draw elements from a list into another list, with optional mapping and filtering. Haskell also has `[1..100]` notation, but this tends to be called "range" syntax (I'm not sure it has an "official" name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [List.range](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#range) and pipeline style read very well togeher.
But it is not as succinct as a list comprehension in python.

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Html


main =
    List.range 1 10
        |> List.map square
        |> List.map String.fromInt
        |> String.join ", "
        |> Html.text


square : Int -> Int
square a =
    a ^ 2
```

Comment: Also `List.filter` for `if`